# Yet Another Question Concerning Conditional Probability v. Intersection of Events

Tags: probability, applications, exponential-distribution

I know that this is a common problem for students, and evidently I'm no exception; but I simply cannot wrap my head around the difference between when we desire the probability of an *intersection* of events and a *conditional* probability.

Here is the example I have in mind (from Ross's *Introduction to Probability Models*):

**Machine $1$ is currently working. Machine $2$ will be put in use at time $t$ from now. If the lifetime of machine $i$ is exponential with rate $\lambda_{i}, i = 1, 2,$ what is the probability that machine $1$ is the first machine to fail?**

The solution is as follows:

$$ \mathbb P(M_1 \lt M_2) = \mathbb P(M_1 \lt M_2 \vert M_1 < t)\cdot \mathbb P(M_1 < t) + \mathbb P(M_1 < M_2 \vert M_1 > t) \cdot \mathbb P(M_1 > t). $$

Now, I understand this solution. It states, in light of Bayes's Rule*, that we desire the probability that the lifetime of machine $1$ is less than the lifetime of machine $2$ *and* the lifetime of machine $1$ is less than $t$ in addition to the probability that the lifetime of machine $1$ is less than the lifetime of machine $2$ *and* the lifetime of machine $1$ is greater than $t$. That all makes sense to me. My question, however, is why is it *not* simply

$$ \mathbb P(M_1 \lt M_2) = \mathbb P(M_1 < t) + \mathbb P(M_1 < M_2 \vert M_1 > t). $$

Linguistically, this seems to satisfy the solution to the problem; i.e., "the probability that the lifetime of machine $1$ is less than $t$, in addition to the probability that the lifetime of machine $1$ is less than that of machine $2$ *given that* the lifetime of machine $1$ is greater than $t$. I understand that the first term here is actually the same as the solution's, and that the solution formulates it as it does for illustrative purposes; but the second term certainly has a different value than that of the solution's.

I hope my question here makes sense. If any further clarification is needed, please let me know. Also, I understand that this exact problem appears elsewhere on stackexchange, but it was more about the computation.

*The Bayes's Rule to which I'm referring is, of course, the following formulation:

$$ \mathbb P(AB) = \mathbb P(A \vert B) \cdot \mathbb P(B) $$

Answer (score 2):

There's no justification for the "*given that* the lifetime of machine $1$ is greater than $t$" part. This is not given. It should be *and*, as in your first paraphrase. If $P(M_1\gt t)$ is very low, the contribution from that term should be very low; whereas in your version its contribution could be up to $1$ no matter how unlikely $M_1\gt t$ is.